# Named router component can't show in my Nativescript angular project

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I create a project use `nativescript-angular`, and I need a login page and a tabview page. I use named route for `TabItem`s.

I refer to the document from nativescript to set my routes, but the named route component can not show. How can show it?

my routing is like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [{
  path: '',
  redirectTo: '/login',
  pathMatch: 'full',
}, {
  path: 'login',
  loadChildren: '~/pages/login/login.module#LoginModule',
}, {
  path: 'index',
  component: TabsComponent,
  children: [{
    path: 'home',
    outlet: 'homeTab',
    component: HomePageComponent
  }, {
    path: 'question',
    outlet: 'questionTab',
    component: QuestionAddComponent
  }]
}];

@NgModule({
  imports: [NativeScriptRouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [NativeScriptRouterModule]
})
```

my tabs component html:

```
<GridLayout>
  <TabView androidTabsPosition="bottom" [(ngModel)]="currentTab" (selectedIndexChanged)="onSelected($event)" id="tabContainer"
    class="icon" selectedTabTextColor="orangered">
    <StackLayout *tabItem="{ title: '&#xe906;Home' }">
      <page-router-outlet name="homeTab"></page-router-outlet>
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout *tabItem="{ title: '&#xe908;Question' }">
      <page-router-outlet name="questionTab"></page-router-outlet>
    </StackLayout>
  </TabView>
</GridLayout>
```

and I turn to index page in login component

```
  constructor(
    private storage: StorageService,
    private router: Router
  ) { }

  turnToFirstPage() {
    // this.router.navigateByUrl('/index/(homeTab:home//questionTab:question)');
    this.router.navigate(['/index', { outlets: { homeTab: ['home'], questionTab: ['question'] } }]);
  }
```

both two methods are invalid.
The `HomePageComponent` and the `QuestionAddComponent` can not show.

Comment: Try removing the StackLayout above `page-router-outlet`. You don't really need it there. `tabItem` directive can be placed on `page-router-outlet` itself.

Comment: I try it before, but is still doesn't work.

Comment: Can you share a Playground sample where the issue can be reproduced?

Comment: [here](https://github.com/khhily/ns_tabview_withlogin.git) is my git url on github, can you help me to see why?

Comment: You have referenced css files in login and index components but those CSS files do not exists. With Angular `<Page>` tag should not be used, it's automatically injected by `page-router-outlet`. And if you want to place more than one component then you must use a layout in login component. So I would suggest you to go through the NativeScript Angular documentation first to get familiar with the component basics, start with small examples before taking a big step. Also checkout the [login-tab-navigation-ng](https://github.com/NativeScript/login-tab-navigation-ng) example.

Comment: ok, thank you, I'll go and see it now.